# Threaded OverlayLayout prints only blank squares instead of circles

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I got two threads printing in a JFrame:
Thread-1: **prints green squares**
Thread-2: **prints blue circles**
To make both figures appear in the JFrame I set the layout for each thread as:

```
    setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));
    setOpaque(false);
```

**Problem: the blue circles appear like blank squares in the JFrame. Only the green squares appear correctly.**

[image]

Here is the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FigurePlacer circle = new FigurePlacer("circle");
        FigurePlacer square = new FigurePlacer("square");

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(circle);
        window.add(square);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Task");
        window.setSize(700, 700);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

And here is the Threaded Class:

```
public class FigurePlacer extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    String figure;
    final int width = 700;
    final int height = 700;
    int x_pos = 0;
    int y_pos = 0;
    int x_width = 50;
    int y_height = 50;

    public FigurePlacer(String str){
        figure = str;
        randomCoord();
        Thread th = new Thread (this);
        th.start();
    }

    private void randomCoord(){ //this ramdomize x,y coord to place a new object
        Random random = new Random();
        x_pos = random.nextInt(width);
        y_pos = random.nextInt(height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println(figure);
        switch (figure){
            case "square":     
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x_pos, y_pos, x_width, y_height);
            break;

            case "circle":
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x_pos, y_pos, x_width, y_height);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){ //paints the objects
        while (true){
            randomCoord();
            paintImmediately(x_pos, y_pos, x_width, y_height);
            try{
                Thread.sleep (50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
    }  

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have a `Canvas` that everyone will draw on? Do you need to toggle visibility in layers or something?

Comment: Correction: there is no canvas in Swing, that was in AWT. Still, I don't see why both threads can't draw on same component.

Answer (score 0):

```
setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));
setOpaque(false);
```

Setting non-opaque on the panel containing the two child panels doesn't do anything.

```
   window.add(circle);
   window.add(square);
```

You need to make the "square" panel non-opaque, so you can see the "circle" panel. (or make both panels non-opaque). The point is when two components are painted on top of one another the top panel needs to be non-opaque).

And your painting code is still incorrect. Have you tried resizing the frame. If you do you will see all the squares disappear.

Comment: Yeah, when resizing I loose every painted object. But I don't know other method that I can apply to do the same Job.

Comment: I moved the setOpaque(false) to the "square" case of the switch codition. Now I just see the green squares getting printed. The "blue circles" (that are blank squares) don't appear anymore.

Comment: @RodrigoFormighieri, `Yeah, when resizing I loose every painted object. But I don't know other method that I can apply to do the same Job` - what??? I gave you a working example of how to point the objects properly in your last question.